# Xamarin load page from Xaml string?

Tags: xaml, xamarin, dynamic, view, load

What I'm trying to accomplish is the following. I'd like a server to send my application a .xaml file or a string containing xaml which would then be displayed as a page within the application. My question is, how can I load a xaml page from a string or from a page file that's sent from the server.  I considered doing it through a webview, but ultimately decided against going with web development.

TLDR: I would like to be able to control the UI + functionality of the application remotely

Answer (score 0):

Try this page to dynamically Loading XAML content.
https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ashish/2007/08/14/dynamically-loading-xaml/